# stored procedure to find out the number of employees that hired in the last n month

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a store procedure that return the number of employees that were hired in last n months in Northwind database. here is what I got:

```
CREATE PROC spGetEmployeeCountByDateHire
@num1 int 
,@num2 int 
,@EmployeeCount int output
 WITH Encryption 
AS 
BEGIN 
select @EmployeeCount = COUNT(*),
DATEDIFF(DAY, HireDate, getdate()) AS Diff 
FROM  Employees where DATEDIFF(DAY, HireDate, getdate()) between @num1 and @num2 
ORDER BY HireDate Desc END
```

I got this err: Msg 141, Level 15, State 1, Procedure spGetEmployeeCountByDateHire, Line 8 A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations.

Can someone help me understand what I did wrong please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error is exactly telling you the reason that you can't combine assigning `count(*)` to a variable and selecting the datediff operation together. Change your select statement as below by removing the `DATEDIFF(DAY, HireDate, getdate()) AS Diff` part from select list

```
select @EmployeeCount = COUNT(*)
FROM  Employees 
where DATEDIFF(DAY, HireDate, getdate()) between @num1 and @num2
```

Comment: Thank you Rahul! as your suggestion It works but I also need remove
    ORDER BY HireDate
 Is there anyway I can keep ORDER BY?

Comment: @user3654088, since you are just counting the records you actually don't a `order by` here; neither it makes sense. So you can safely remove it. Also, don't forget to accept the answer by clicking the check button under voting button.